# Saving to a file issue

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

i am trying to save the list that is generated to a file, i see the print out of the list fine but it will not write to the compoundlist.csv file. i am not sure what i am doing wrong, i have tried to write after the list is generated and also during the loop. I have gotten the same result.

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import os
import csv


def make_soup(url):
    thepage = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    soupdata = BeautifulSoup(thepage, "html.parser")
    return soupdata


compoundlist = []
soup = make_soup("http://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?ko00020")
i = 1
file = open("Compoundlist.csv", "wb")
for record in soup.findAll("nobr"):
    compound = ''
    if (record.text[0] == "C" and record.text[1] == '0') or (record.text[0] == "C" and record.text[1] == '1'):
        compoundlist = "http://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?cpd:" + record.text
        file.write(compoundlist)
        print(compoundlist)
```

Comment: try to encode the result by using compoundlist.encode("utf-8") at second last line as file.write(compoundlist.encode("utf-8"))

Comment: That code fails with `TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface` but if I just open the file with "w" it works. You don't add a newline so its all one long string. You don't close the file so there is a chance that it is discarded on your system. But I certainly don't get the same error you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the following to the end of your code

```
file.close()
```

To flush the open file buffer into the file

Comment: Thanks! that fixed the issue, is it always important to close the file to write to it?

Comment: @visionarylearner although it is highly recommended to always close the file when you are done with it. Alternatively you could flush the buffer using `file.flush()` which effectively does the same thing but will still let you write to the file afterward and is normally used when writing large amounts of data